# How To Check when a CheckBox is Checked In An IF statement And then perform an action in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a question about how to check if a checkbox is checked programmatically in C# I'm currently busy with writing an operating system for spacecrafts in C# for crew members and passengers, it's not the meaning to publish it but I built it for testing with a complex network of resources and devices and maybe in the future an OS for spacecrafts but not now.

The plan is to check if a checkbox is checked so the right crew-member gets the right access to the speech recognition engine and gets the permission to log-on to the right form!

I have done this by writing this code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.IO;

namespace HyperPod_OS
{
    public partial class Login_Form : Form
    {

        // SETS THE INTS FOR THE AUTO TEXTBOX //

        private int a = 0;
        private int b = 0;
        private int c = 0;
        private int d = 0;
        private int f = 0;
        private int g = 0;
        private int h = 0;
        private int i = 0;
        private int j = 0;
        private int k = 0;
        private int l = 0;
        private int m = 0;

        // SPEECH ENGINE AND SYNTHESIZER //

        SpeechSynthesizer HelpAssistant = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        SpeechRecognitionEngine ReconEngine_Programmer = new     SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        SpeechRecognitionEngine ReconEngine_Data_Specialist = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        SpeechRecognitionEngine ReconEngine_Communication_Specialist = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        SpeechRecognitionEngine ReconEngine_System_Manager = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        SpeechRecognitionEngine ReconEngine_Captain = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        SpeechRecognitionEngine ReconEngine_Doctor = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        // LOADS THE FORM2 FOR BLENDING //

       Login_Form_Empty loginformempty;

       public Login_Form()
       {

            InitializeComponent();

            // LOADS THE GRAMMAR OBJECT FOR ALL CREW CLASSES //

                ReconEngine_Programmer.SpeechRecognized += new         EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(ReconEngine_Programmer_SpeechRecognized);
                LoadGrammar_Programmer();
                ReconEngine_Programmer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

                ReconEngine_Data_Specialist.SpeechRecognized += new    EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(ReconEngine_Data_Specialist_SpeechRecognized);
                LoadGrammar_Data_Specialist();
                ReconEngine_Data_Specialist.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

                ReconEngine_Communication_Specialist.SpeechRecognized += new  EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(ReconEngine_Communication_Specialist_SpeechRecognized);
                LoadGrammar_Communication_Specialist();
      ReconEngine_Communication_Specialist.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        ReconEngine_System_Manager.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(ReconEngine_System_Manager_SpeechRecognized);
        LoadGrammar_System_Manager();
        ReconEngine_System_Manager.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        ReconEngine_Captain.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(ReconEngine_Captain_SpeechRecognized);
        LoadGrammar_Captain();
        ReconEngine_Captain.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        ReconEngine_Doctor.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(ReconEngine_Doctor_SpeechRecognized);
        LoadGrammar_Doctor();
        ReconEngine_Doctor.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        // SETS THE SCREEN TO SEMI-TRANSPARENT //

        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 190, 255);
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(0, 190, 255);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

        // OPENS FORM4 AND SETS THE POSITION OF IT //

        loginformempty = new Login_Form_Empty();
        loginformempty.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        loginformempty.Location = new Point(200, 200);
        loginformempty.Show();

        // SETS THE METHOD OBJECTS // 

        this.LocationChanged += new EventHandler(Login_Form_LocationChanged);
        this.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(Login_Form_SizeChanged);
        this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Login_Form_FormClosed);

        // LOADS THE SPEECH ENGINE ON CHECKBOX //

        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {

            ReconEngine_Programmer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        }

        if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
        {

            ReconEngine_Data_Specialist.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        }

        if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
        {

                ReconEngine_Communication_Specialist.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        }

        if (checkBox4.Checked == true)
        {

            ReconEngine_System_Manager.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        }

        if (checkBox5.Checked == true)
        {

            ReconEngine_Captain.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        }

        if (checkBox6.Checked == true)
        {

            ReconEngine_Doctor.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        }
    }
```

It doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Comment: What doesn't work? Did you try putting breakpoints?

Comment: Who is checking the checkboxes and when?

Comment: the checkbox is checked by a numpad (authentication-form) where the crew members insert the login code via a numpad then they come to the login-form where they use the speech recognition for login in to the corresponding form (example: programmer uses: login as programmer. and then login)

Comment: and btw iam dutch :)

Comment: You put your 'checking' in the wrong place, right after they are made. You only check then so afterwards they do nothing (of course)

Comment: Lol I am dutch too....

Comment: You're calling `loginformempty.Show();` which does not block. You might try `loginformempty.ShowDialog();` _(rather answer in english, so more people can enjoy our quests)_   =)   Also the response of the login form is never handled? how would you know if a user is successfully logged in?

Comment: can you send me the code but then perfect? and for the successfully loged in part i use a remote sql database on one of my servers

Comment: this is not the whole code

Comment: @BradleyMethorst Sorry, I can't, I don't know the assignment and its not my job to provide a complete solution. If you're stuck with a bug, you should provide a clear and runnable code-snip which hold the bug. So we could help.

Comment: @BradleyMethorst You should name your controls better. ReconEngine_ProgrammerCheckBox.Checked is much more readable than checkBox1.Checked.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing right now is checking the boxes just after they have been created. The user had no chance to change them.

You can do:
In the constructor add an event to the [changed event of each Checkbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
checkBox.CheckedChanged += DoSomething;
```

and let it call a method

```
public void DoSomethning(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Another way is to add a button to the form and call a method when it is [pressed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: you will still need the check, but this calls the method whenever the user changes the box

Comment: its not the meaning that the users checks the checkboxes!!! its for leading the crewmembers to the right speech recognition engine

Comment: the checkboxes will be unvisible when the code works

Comment: You code check whether they are on `==` to set them you would use `=`, But that wouldn't make sense with the code you have

Answer (score 0):

Checked property is a boolean itself, so you can just do this:

```
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                ReconEngine_Programmer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

            }
            else
            {
                //not checked
            }

            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                ReconEngine_Data_Specialist.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

            }
            else
            {
                //not checked
            }
```

This is a very simple comparision itself, it cannot fail. If you are having problems with the checked value you might take a look on how you set it.

You also can check for the `CheckedChanged` and see if it is simpler for you to manage that event and do your business logic inside the handler.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this and my method of hacking it together was to grab the text from the selected radio button and pass that along to a switch statement:

```
     /**
     * Unified way to get text from a selected FlowLayoutPanel.
     */
    private string GetTextCheckedButton(FlowLayoutPanel flp)
    {
        string text = flp.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked).Text;
        return text;
    }
```

As you can see, it finds the selected radio button from the flow layout panel and returns that. You could do it so it returns an array / list of strings to be passed along.

You'll also need a Checked event handler on the button itself, which I feel you might be missing.

Comment: the buttons (numpad) and the checkboxes are not on the same form, the user types in the code (numpad) in the authentication-form and go to the login form where the system checks the checkboxes and asigns the checkbox to the speech-engine and the user can login with the right speech engine

Answer (score 0):

First off, you put your checkboxes in the same method as initializer.
Your code works (although if's can be shortened to: `if(checkBox1.checked)`).
Make a checker function somewhere if you want to check them all at the same time (and call that when you need it)

Or if you want to check at any time assign event handlers:

```
checkBox1.CheckedChanged += CheckBox1Changed;


public void CheckBox1Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(checkbox1.checked)
   {

   }
}
```